# PostgreSQL vs MongoDB vs in-RAM kdTree for KNN queries?

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, tree, geolocation, geospatial

I understand that PostgreSQL (PostGIS) and MongoDB are both doing a great job with kNN queries (k nearest neighbors).

I am having a hard time deciding which one is more suitable for my application, so that it could scale easily and efficiently. 
I want to make k nearest neighbors queries on GPS coordinates, without having a bounding box.

I will have potentially much more read requests than write requests (update the tree).

So far, I have an in-RAM solution of a Kd-tree but I'm afraid I will have consistency issues at scale..
If you can think of any solution I'd be happy to hear as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is an interesting question. I've worked with all 3 technologies you mention. Will you only be interested in kNN to a single point in each query rather than multiple kNN from multiple points? This is important because there is two distance operators, <-> and <#> in Postgres (not Postgis), but that can be used for blindingly fast kNN search in Postgis, but the one gotcha is that one of the geometries needs to be a constant.

Comment: I have a database of a millions of (latitude, longitude).
My requests are: get the 100 knn from (30.234, 12.3455).
So I guess it would fit your description.
Do you believe PostGIS is a good fit for the kNN general problem (non-bounded --> I won't provide a "radius" when querying).
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I do. Mongo does handle this kind of query too, via geoNear, but geohashing isn't as quick as `order by geom <-> point limit x` type queries on a Postgres gist index. I would recommend testing on a decent subset of your data, naturally, but that is my experience.

Answer (score 1):

A good in-memory index solution *will* beat the database systems by magnitudes.

Do you have a lot of updates? kd-trees aren't very good at updating; usually one would rebuild the tree frequently to accomodate added points. A kd-tree using "node" objects to allow for such cases easily needs two times as much memory as a tree that doesn't; so this can quickly pay off.

Transaction safety is a pain to implement yourself; a good DBMS may be helpful there. Yet, you may still decide to only use the DBMS for recovery backing, and build in-memory trees (kd or R-trees, which are often much faster) from that using bulk loading.

MongoDB: stay away from this hype. PostgresSQL is good, but I'm not convinced of their GIS functionality. Nevertheless, Postgres may be the best you get in opensource, maybe even outside.

In the end: **benchmark, benchmark, benchmark**. Every data and query workload is different. An approach that works well for one scenario (such as geo hashing) may be turn out to be useless in another scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I actually like much better the in-memory kd/r-tree solution, but I'm afraid it will not scale correctly.

What happens when my PaaS auto-scales and creates another instance of the application, then I may have issues with consistency between the instances.

Do you know of any way to implement kd/r-tree with some kind of memcached/redis backed Elasticache (AWS), or any similar solution?

Thanks

Comment: There is something called [extremeDB] (http://www.mcobject.com/extremedbfamily.shtml) that claims to do in-memory r-trees enabling nearest neighbour searches. I haven't used it,  so can't offer any more details.

Comment: Anony-Mousse I agree with you on basically everything, as you will see from my comments above. Why are you not convinced by Postgres's spatial functionality though. Are you talking about Postgis and its 500 odd vector/raster/topology functions, or were you referring to the <-> and <#> operators of Posgtres, which can be utilized for very fast knn search, albeit still disk based. MongoDB is, as you say, to be avoided, but KD trees are not without their issues either.